# Ways to debug React Native Application

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to debug my React Native Application. As my React Native application is created using expo. I had tried to use React Native Debugger which is introduced at the Expo documentation. But it doesn't work for my project. I had also tried to use some others technique to debug my React Native Application such as debug at Vs code, Flipper and debug at chrome. But it keep showing me error message and my app is crashed after clicking on Remote Debugging Js.

Here is the error message on my Vs Code.
[image: Error message from VS Code]

Here is the error message from my Android Emulator.

[image: Error Message from Android Emulator]

Is there any other debugging tools for React Native? Because the debugging tools I listed is not work on my machine. Or anyone know the solution to resolve this error.

Thanks for help! Really Appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

some times you need to run with same network just press ctrl+M/Shake the device you will get a popup just click on the settings and on debugging add your ip like :

```
129.190.1.2:8081
```

you will get the ip by system

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For the localhost id, is't always 8081 for all machine? Or how can i know the localhost id for debugging?

Comment: I tried to press Ctrl + M to open the popup, but there is no settings on the popup.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is not going to be the straight solution for this, But worth trying the following

- Updating the node.js version
- Change the emulator with updated android version or try with real device

In my case, when nothing worked I had to create a new/duplicate RN app with updated RN version and copying the source code